# github deploy key not working for my cyberpanel user

Tags: ssh

I have a site on CyberPanel, user "thows3051" and want to use git to manage my site. But when I try `ssh -T git@github.com` I get `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`.

If I ssh into the server on that user ssh thows3051@mysite.com, into the .ssh directory, there is a `thows3051.pub` file which I copied the contents into the repo on github under "deploy keys".

**EDIT**

Was able to explicitly use the correct key with `ssh -i ~/.ssh/thows3051 -T git@github.com` which shows `You've successfully authenticated...`.

So my question is why isn't the user using the right ssh key?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix it. I'm not sure what key was being used, if any?

But if you create a file in `~/.ssh/config`, you can put the following inside:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/thows3051
```

And it will use that key.

Note that you can set specific keys for certain hosts, for example:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.key
```

Comment: This is just how ssh works. You might want to add "IdentitiesOnly" here; see the ssh documentation.

Comment: @torek I guess I'm just used to the IdentifyFile being added to the config by default on most setups, like ubuntu desktop etc?

Comment: I haven't used any particular Ubuntu desktop setup (I've used Ubuntu, but remote ssh-ing in from a mac laptop, normally). So I just use ssh in the usual ssh ways... :-)